# Convert from binary to 64-Bit float

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point

I have used the following function to create a buffer from a **64-bit** float: `new Float64Array([127.375]).buffer`. The `Buffer` class **does** have a method, `readFloatBE` (or `readFloatLE`) for little Endian, but both read **32-bit** floats.

My question is: how can I read a **64-bit** float from a Buffer in Node.js?

Comment: `.readDoubleLE()` or `.readDoubleBE()`

Comment: @Pointy thanks! That works! You might as well add an answer for the extra rep of getting it accepted 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Buffer` class also has `.readDoubleLE()` and `.readDoubleBE()` for double-precision numbers (which are the "normal" JavaScript numeric type).